# Is OneDrive required to be installed if I want to use OneNote 2016 on the same desktop?

Tags: installation, onedrive, microsoft-onenote-2016

Right now, OneDrive starts up with my computer and I aslo use Onenote 2016.  Can I uninstall OneDrive with no noticiable effect on OneNote?  (I still want to save all notebooks on OneDrive.)

I am doing this in order to save CPU and RAM.  I notice that OneNote doesn't seem to access the OneDrive folder but it seems to go directly to the web to find the latest copy.

So, I'm guessing that OneDrive would be unnecessary for a fully functional OneNote 2016.  Is it true?

Comment: Hey, User173724,I'm not a computer guy so I have no idea if what you say is true, but I would think OneDrive would take a lot of resources.  It seems like a resource heavy program.  I could have OneNote save to Google Drive but I think that would cause complications.  I started savings things to OneDrive

Comment: Hey, User173724,OneDrive seems resource heavy and laggy. Do I really need OneDrive to sync with OneNote? If I am using Onenote, I could save info after any change so it would push info to OneDrive online.  And I can have OneNote pull any info from OneDrive every 10 minutes. (I have about 20 startups and even with 32 gigs of RAM, it's starting to slow my comp down by a lot.)

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry about uninstalling OneDrive. Any benefits you would see from that would be tiny, and the lack of syncing would outweigh it.

Just disable OneDrive from running at startup, and manually launch it when you want to sync.

Though to be honest, it barely affects startup, what makes you want to uninstall it?

To answer your second question, it will work, but you cannot sync with OneDrive.